# WordPress or building site on own? Which is more cost efficient?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, web, hosting

I need to host a website. I have a pretty much experience in working with JavaScript and PHP. What would be better, building up a website on my own and then hosting it using some thrid party server or using WordPress?
I'm based in India and want to save money.

Comment: I say WordPress.

Comment: Wordpress comes with overhead, but it's a lot faster to deploy a Wordpress site (there are thousands of themes and plugins). It depends on how complex your logic is, if it's just a presentation site or a shop with 1000 or less products and your time is limited, then Wordpress, otherwise, custom site.

Comment: This is _far_ too broad for Stack Overflow, and also primarily opinion-based. Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic], and also keep in mind that there are different kinds of "cost".

Answer (score 1):

Building a website will take a hell of a lot of time. Even if you know all the necessary languages, 9/10 times you're going to want to add something to site of which you don't have the knowledge to add it and will try and figure out how to add it in. Overall it's just about what you want to do. More cost efficient? Well you're not getting viewers if your site isn't active and that means you won't possibly make any money. I would suggest you use WordPress for now and in your spare time you work on building up your site in which you can use in a future overhaul of the site. This will not only save you money, but then you have a site in place already and can overhaul the new site update when you're ready.